# How receive the full DOM path of a div element and check CSS height element

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

This is example a webpage where it found the **school** id:

```
<html><body><div><table style="height:2px"><tr><td style="height:10px"><div id="school">
```

Current i have this JavaScript code, that code detect well the **school** id and it provide me the DOM path to that div element.
But now i want to check also if there is a **height** style element, and if there is a value. Show me then that value with the `alert(y)`.

```
var path = [];
var el = document.getElementById('school');
do {
    var qq = path.unshift(el.nodeName);
    if (el.nodeName.currentStyle){ var y = qq.currentStyle["Height"]; alert(y);}
 else {var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el.nodeName,null).getPropertyValue("Height");alert(y);}

} while ((el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'html') && (el = el.parentNode))
```

But that doesn't work.
Question: Need help to read all the current `height` values (of the path to `div id="school"` element).

Normal it must alert me this value:
2px
10px

If need more information, just comment here below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getComputedStyle(el.nodeName,null)` should be `getComputedStyle(el,null)`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GRYj/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the case of "Height" to lowercase in the code since it's case-sensitive ("height").

For example for IE,

```
.currentStyle["height"];
```

and for Mozilla,

```
.getPropertyValue("height");
```

When this is run, it returns *auto* for the height of div **school**. To find the actual height of div **school** you'll need to find the heights of its parent `<td>` element, and parent `<table>` element.

For example, the following code in IE returns the height for the parent `<table>` of div **school**, and returns *2px*.

```
.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.currentStyle["height"];
```

and the following returns the height for the parent `<td>` of div **school** and returns *10px*.

```
.parentNode.currentStyle["height"];
```